# Using variables inside of an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, file-io

So I have this piece of code in my Employee class:

```
     public static double HoursWorked;
     public static double HourlyWage;  

    public static double AnnualGrossSalary = HoursWorked*HourlyWage*52;

    public double getAnnualGrossSalary(){       
        return AnnualGrossSalary;
    }
```

Now I've set these to static because I'm using AnnualGrossSalary inside other classes and for some reason they're asking me to make it static, won't argue with compiler (Java newbie!)

And basically in my main class I have:

```
report.println(ArrEmployee.get(0).getAnnualGrossSalary());
```

Where this annual gross salary is supposed to be printed in a file. My array list `ArrEmployee`contains Employee objects containing variables `HoursWorked` and `HourlyWage`.

Now the problem I'm getting is in the report I'm only getting 0.0, when `HourlyWage` and `HoursWorked` when they're both > 0... I can't seem to find the problem here, can anyone help?

Comment: Every instance of your `Employee` will now have the same values of `HoursWorked`, `HourlyWage` and `AnnualGrossSalary`.  `static` is not a cross object communication mechanism and should be used this way.  This WILL blow up in your face

Comment: `AnnualGrossSalary` should be calculated with requested and not held within a variable...

Comment: @MadProgrammer But the problem is when I call the variable inside of other methods in other classes, it keeps saying it needs to be static

Comment: No, it doesn't, you need to create instances of the class and stop using the class name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't each `Employee` have their own salary? Looks like they should not be static.

Something like:

```
private double hoursWorked, hourlyWage;

public double getAnnualGrossSalary(){
  return hoursWorked * hourlyWage * 52;
}
```

If you also need access to those variables you should use setters and getters to preserve encapsulation.

```
public void setHoursWorked(double hours){
  this.hoursWorked = hours;
}

public double getHoursWorked(){
  return this.hoursWorked;
}
```

You could then use them in an ArrayList like this:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setHourlyWage(12.5);
emp.setHoursWorked(100);

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(emp);

for(Employee e : employees){
  System.out.println(e.getAnnualGrossSalary());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, the problem is, I can't seem to use the variables from my Employee class inside other classes without it being static, but if I set it to static, it breaks my whole program.. Any idea? For example the getAnnualGrossSalary() method, I need to use that value in other classes, how would I do that without it being static?

Comment: Well, to use it you will need to get an instance of an employee, since it is always an attribute of an employee. You need to get the instances there somehow, and then call their member functions to get the values.